How to modify PlotTheme->"Marketing"?
The code is lent from this and later modified as per need, as shown below:
   Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, PlotTheme -> "Marketing"] /. 
     Thread[{GrayLevel[0, 0.5`], GrayLevel[0, 0.9`], 
        GrayLevel[0, 0.9`]} -> {Opacity[0.01, Green], 
        Opacity[0.01, Green], Opacity[0.9, None]}]


I want only the XY plane in colour and YZ and ZX in white, just as above. However, instead of a single colour XY plane, I am getting an additional black diagonal line joining two corners. How do I remove that and get a single-colour plane instead?
The workaround is to use Epilog and Rectangle below the curve parallel to the XY plane, which I don't want to do.
I want to learn if there is a way to do this without using Epilog by modifying the above code.
Thank you

Generate the desired graphics object to be used with the main plot:
floor = Graphics3D[{FaceForm[{Green, Green}], JoinForm["Round"], EdgeForm[None], 
  Polygon[{Scaled[{0, 0, 0}], Scaled[{0, 1, 0}], 
     Scaled[{1, 1, 0}], Scaled[{1, 0, 0}]}]}];

Add the option DisplayFunction -> (Show[#, floor] &) before PlotTheme ->"Marketing" in Plot3D:
Plot3D[Sin[x  y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3},
 DisplayFunction -> (Show[#, floor] &), 
 PlotTheme -> "Marketing"]


ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[x], Cos[x], x}, {x, 0, 2  π}, 
 DisplayFunction -> (Show[#, floor] &), PlotTheme -> "Marketing"]


 $Version


"14.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)"



It is not working when I use ParametricPlot3D.
I am trying to plot this with the modification provided by you. ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[x], Cos[x], x}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]},  DisplayFunction -> (Show[#, floor] &), PlotTheme -> "Marketing"]. However it's not working

@user444, I updated with the picture I get using ParametricPlot3D[...].

p3d = Plot3D[Sin[x  y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, PlotTheme -> "Marketing"];

vc = Thread[Table[{Green, Opacity[0], Opacity[0]}, 4]];

p3d /. 
 HoldPattern[VertexColors -> _] :> Rule[VertexColors, Last[vc = RotateLeft[vc]]]


